# How to make file placed on sdcard writeable in android

Tags: android, file, file-io, sd-card

I wanted to make a file in sdcard writeable but unable to do this I've tried following code but it didn't work.

```
public static void makeWriteable(String filename){
    File file = new File(filename);
    if(file.exists()){
        file.setWritable(true);
    }
}
```

I've also tried the following method, but can't get it right:

```
file.setWritable(true, false);
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you write the permission statement in manifest file

Comment: yes I do have writes permission.

Answer (score 0):

Set this in your application :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Then you can write any file from your application to the SDCard.